# Adding JQuery UI styles on a single page application

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

After recently completing a single page AJAX application with jQuery and jQuery UI, I discovered a few jQuery form styles I had previously skipped over in their documentation.

Adding the classes:

```
 text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
```

Is there an easy way I can implement these styles to all text inputs throughout the entirety of my AJAX driven application?  I would like to find a resolution without having to resort to any of the following:

1. Paste the previous mentioned classes into every input form (I have quite a few and it looks terribly messy... unless this is best practice, it doesn't feel quite right though)
2. Having to add "$("input").addClass()" to every AJAX callbacks (seems messy too).

I would rather not use any more jQuery plugins but would be willing to consider one depending on how simple it would make this task...

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do this at your ui's css stylesheet

```
 text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all, input{....}
```

will give the same effects to all your inputs.

Comment: Well, I am trying to utilize the CSS that the jQuery UI themes provide.  I think as a last resort I could probably copy the CSS from the theme I am using into an input CSS selector.  I have a few themes my application can switch through making that slightly more complicated though...